# FQL and Graph API in iOS

Tags: facebook, ios, facebook-fql

have anyone used FQL of graph API in iOS?
I am trying to get users posts from different groups 
I have read FQL documentation 
but I  need to see an example to help me proceed?
please help

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Here is an example:

```
    NSMutableDictionary * params = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                @"SELECT uid,name FROM user WHERE uid=4", @"query",
                                nil];
[facebook   requestWithMethodName: @"fql.query"
                         andParams: params
                     andHttpMethod: @"POST"
                       andDelegate: self];
```

Answer (score 8):

In the last iOS SDK, the method mentioned by Bertrand doesn't exists. Now you should do it this way:

```
NSString *query = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"YOUR_QUERY_HERE"];  //begins from SELECT........

NSMutableDictionary * params = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                query, @"q",
                                nil];

FBRequest *request = [FBRequest requestWithGraphPath:@"/fql" parameters:params HTTPMethod:@"GET"];

[request startWithCompletionHandler:^(FBRequestConnection *connection, id result, NSError *error) {
    //do your stuff
}];

//or you can do it also with the following class method:

[FBRequestConnection startWithGraphPath:@"/fql" parameters:params HTTPMethod:@"GET" completionHandler:^(FBRequestConnection *connection,
                                          id result,
                                          NSError *error) {
    //do your stuff
}];
```

Source: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/howtos/run-fql-queries-ios-sdk/