# Get data from facebook using IOS SDK

Tags: ios, facebook, graph, path

In facebook when we type some text on "search", we get a list of pages corresponding to the text. Similarly, is it possible to search from the iphone app using graph path. I need to pass a text from my app to facebook and get all the related data/pages back.
Please help!!

Comment: What have you tried?  SO is isn't so much a do it for me site - you present what you've tried, what issues you're hitting and folks give you pointers (not full solutions).

Comment: I just need an idea of how to start with. I googled a lot and couldn't find out how to pass text to facebook in the first place.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should get your started:

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/mobile/ios/build/

It's a tutorial which walks you through interacting with the fb API on iOS.

And here's the Facebook query language:

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/

[FQL and Graph API in iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4941430/fql-and-graph-api-in-ios)