# How to know if my facebook friends have my app?

Tags: ios, xcode, facebook, facebook-graph-api, installed-applications

i have a huge problem that i think you might solve in a second. I've tried thousands of different codes, but i haven't succeeded in none of them, some were using an old Facebook SDK for instance. My issue is simple, i want the user to know how many of his Facebook friends got the application, like that i could sent them a notification through my iPhone app. I found a field called fields=installed in the Graph API, but how can i code a method to know who are those friends, and how many they are.

Answer (score 2):

You query the friends field `/me/friends?fields=installed,name`

Which will give a list of friends with either installed field set or not.

Comment: I try this but I'm note sure of  the code I've written, can you send me the exact code ? Thanks !

Comment: I made [FBRequest requestWithGraphPath:@"/me/friends?fields=installed,id"] but have 0 friends installed. :/ I would need a .count and the list of the corresponding ids

Comment: Do you have friends that use your app? this is easily verifiable by checking the API explorer.

Comment: This is the strange part, there is an other dev who is an admin of the facebook app, and when i make a GET graph api query, i see him with the installed = true field, but i always see 0 friend on the console

Comment: And he is a friend of mine on facebook as well, forgot to mention that

Answer (score 1):

This  [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17212045/1352847) could answer you question. Though we have to search through result for installed tag

It uses the new FB SDK