# How to get Page's Posts by Others

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, posts, fan-page

I need to pull the 'Posts by Others' from my Facebook Page and display them on my site. Spent the afternoon fiddling around with the API and was able to see posts made by the page, but not others. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Steve, I just found another solution, you can use the Graph API using FQL.

Just make a call to the following:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/fql?q=SELECT post_id, created_time , app_data, type, actor_id, target_id, message FROM stream WHERE  source_id = YOUR_PAGE_ID AND actor_id != YOUR_PAGE_ID&access_token=YOUR_ACCESS_TOKEN
```

If you need more variables, you just need to put them after SELECT, and you can check them out here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/stream

On iOS, you **don't need to put the access token in the query.** To check how to do it with the latest iOS SDK, see my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/14357179/675486

Comment: Can this be achieved with the Graph API?

Answer (score 1):

Got it, they are in the 'feed' field along with posts by the page. I was hoping for something that would just give posts by others, but I can filter out the ones posted by the page.

Comment: Could you find a solution where you don't need to filter it, I mean, to receive directly from the API only other's posts?