# Querying old links from public Facebook page returns an empty set

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql

I am trying to fetch links that were posted on a public Facebook page sometime ago, in 2011 for example. Specifically, the Arabic CNN page on facebook: http://www.facebook.com/CNNArabic

Things I tried:
 
1- Graph API, a query like this:
[CNNArabic/links?fields=id,name,link,created_time&limit=25&until=2012-05-15](http://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer?method=GET&path=102581028206/links?fields=id,name,link,created_time&limit=25&until=2012-05-15)

2- FQL
**SELECT link_id, url, created_time FROM link WHERE owner = 102581028206 and created_time < 1337085958 LIMIT 100**

Both give an empty data set while there is data on the page on or before this date.

Other things I noticed:
1-If I changed the date to something like 2013-01-17 (which is yesterday), it works fine.
2-If I changed the date to something like 2012-12-17 (about a month ago), an empty data set is returned, however if I followed the next page links in the returned data set from the query in number 1 above until I pass by this date I actually get data.

I tried writing code that kept following the next page pointers until I reach the links on the date I want. However I need data much older (say in 2011) and the result set gets exhausted say 2 or 3 months earlier than now, in other words no more next links are returned so I actually can never reach that old data.

To cut this short:
is there a way I can query links that were posted on a public page before a specified date?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Querying the page's `feed` works in the Graph API:

```
/102581028206/feed?fields=id,link,name,created_time&limit=25&until=2012-05-15
```

This returns all the posts. There *should* be a way to filter this using [field expansion](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/field_expansion/), but I couldn't get the few things I tried to work.

You can get this filtered for links only with FQL on the `stream` table:

```
SELECT message, attachment, created_time FROM stream WHERE source_id = 102581028206 
    AND created_time < strtotime('2012-05-15') AND type=80 LIMIT 10
```

Links are `type=80`.

Comment: Well, I know this, thanks anyway but I couldn't figure out how to filter for the links. Any ideas?

Comment: The FQL returns only links.